# На MacOS локальный сервер MAMP не дает открыть дочерние страницы

Tags: wordpress, macos, mamp

Опишу.
Перешел на MacOS, настраиваю окружение. Установил MAMP и всё необходимое.
Пришло время локально развернуть проект, которым сейчас занимаюсь. Он на WordPress.
Проект уже готовый с большим числом страниц.
И вот беда в том, что через MAMP открывает только корневую страницу, страницу 404 и страницу админ-панели, при переходе по остальным страницам выдает ошибку самого Nginx 404 Not Found.
При этом, для тестов, создал новый проект wp, и заметил, что в нем все страницы создаваемые выглядят вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть вместо нормальных роутов по сути get-параметры.
Решил попытаться на своем сайте вместо условного localhost:8888/site/catalog вписать localhost:8888/site/?page_id=1052 (id страницы каталог), но всё равно получаю редирект на /catalog и nginx 404

В общем, нужно помощь, т.к сама, наверное, разобраться не смогу

Comment: `Проект уже готовый с большим числом страниц.` -- Вы проект переносили каким-то образом откуда-то? Какие шаги предпринимались. Есть ли в корне файл `.htaccess`?

Comment: .htaccess есть, да. в гите все важные файлы есть, с сервера переносилось всё, что касается медиа. бд с сервера опять же

Comment: htaccess выглядит вот так

Comment: <IfModule mod_mime.c>
 AddType image/webp .webp
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>